# Unable to connect the web page when deploy Kubernetes service on AWS EC2

Tags: kubernetes, ansible, devops, kubernetes-pod

I can not access to the web page even thought the kubernete has deployed the services on AWS EC2 successfully and i can check that it is running and

Web Browser Link : EC2 public IP (and i have tried private IP and external ip from kubectl get services):8080 (also have tried 31200)

Result:

```
Unable to connect
```

i also try to below command but the result is  with failed connection` refused.

```
wget 127.0.0.1:8080 and wget 127.0.0.1:31200
```

Firewall rule for 8080 and 31200 are opened.

i am deploying an web application through kubernetes deployment and service on AWS EC2 as below command

```
ansible-playbook -i /opt/kubernetes/hosts /opt/kubernetes/website-deployment.yml;
ansible-playbook -i /opt/kubernetes/hosts /opt/kubernetes/website-service.yml;
```

The deployment.yml is

```
---
- name: Create pods using deployment 
  hosts: localhost
  become: true
  user: root

  tasks: 
  - name: create a deployment
    command: kubectl apply -f /opt/docker/website-deployment.yml

  - name: update deployment with new pods whenever image updated in docker hub
    command: kubectl rollout restart deployment.v1.apps/website-deployment
```

The service yml is

```
---
- name: create service for deployment
  hosts: localhost
  become: true
  user: root

  tasks:
  - name: create a service
    command: kubectl apply -f /opt/docker/website-service.yml
```

when i run

```
kubectl get services

NAME              TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP                                                               PORT(S)          AGE
web-service   LoadBalancer   100.64.119.242   afefc1ecf599f4a16a12aa2fe5dbbb30-614667794.ap-south-1.elb.amazonaws.com   8080:***31200***/TCP   12h
kubernetes        ClusterIP      100.64.0.1       <none>                                                                    443/TCP          36h

kubectl get pods
NAME                                  READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
web-service-deployment-7df8c9bc7c-g9hkp   1/1     Running   0          135m
web-service-deployment-7df8c9bc7c-pmtlv   1/1     Running   0          135m
sample-nginx                          1/1     Running   0          38h
```

Comment: provide output of kubectl describe svc web-service. have u tried accessing it via the external IP?

Comment: Hi Arghya, yes i have tried external IP as well but no luck

Comment: When you say that you tried `wget 127.0.0.1:8080 and wget 127.0.0.1:31200`, you mean that you tried it from inside your website pod?